# jstree - do something after AJAX done

Tags: javascript, ajax, jstree

Simple question, I want to execute something everytime jstree AJAX load done.. for example `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();`..

Below is my code:

```
$('#jstree').jstree({
  "core": {
    'themes': {
      //dots:false
    },
    'data': {
      'url': function(node) {
        return 'http://localhost:4044/admin/users/tree/get';
      },
      'success': function(){ //currently, this is not working
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      }
    }
  },
  'types': {
    'default': {
      "icon": "mdi mdi-account text-warning-dark",
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "types"
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why...Actually the `success` attribute is already correct, but in order to make the `tooltip` working, I need to include it inside `setTimeout`...

I wrote the code below, and it works!

```
$('#jstree').jstree({
  "core": {
    'themes': {
      //dots:false
    },
    'data': {
      'url': function(node) {
        return 'http://localhost:4044/admin/users/tree/get';
      },
      'success': function(){
        setTimeout(function(){ //add setTimeout
          $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        }, 100);
      }
    }
  },
  'types': {
    'default': {
      "icon": "mdi mdi-account text-warning-dark",
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "types"
  ]
});
```